# htaccess redirect outcome not as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I hope someone can help me with the following problem.

I have a multiple language site with the language as a folder like
`example.com/se/post`

I want to get the language separated by domain like `example.se`.
So far no problem with a DNS alias and WPML plugin.

The problem I have is that I want to redirect `example.com/se/post` to `example.se/post`. I try to use this rule in the `.HTACCESS` file but it changes the URL to `example.se/se` with the `/se` that I do not need. I'm not very familiar with the rewrite engine in `.HTACCESS` file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?nofairytales\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sv(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.nofairytales.se%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: How many language codes? Presumably this is for all languages? And the lang code always matches the target TLD? (Although in your rule you are redirecting from `sv` to `se`?) Is there always a `<post>` part in the URL?

Comment: Apart from the sv/se mixup, this should redirect you from `http://www.nofairytales.se/se/post` to `http://www.nofairytales.se/se/post`. The latter is not what you wanted, of course - you can't just append the full REQUEST_URI, when you want to remove part of it. Checking on the REQUEST_URI using a RewriteCond is rather superfluous to begin with - the RewriteRule can match the URL path fine on its own. Something like `RewriteRule ^se(/?.+)?$ http://www.nofairytales.se$1 [L,R=301]` (without that second RewriteCond) should come close to what you want.

Comment: @CBroe `^se(/?.+)?$` - By making the slash _optional_ inside the group, you are now matching `se<anything>`, rather than `se/<anything>` which could result in a malformed redirect, or worse, redirect to another site entirely (XSS exploit).

Comment: "in `.HTACCESS` file." - Note that the `.htaccess` filename _must_ be all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?nofairytales\.nl$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sv(/.*)?$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.se%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

This is close... you are capturing the URL-path (`/post` part) in the preceding *condition* but not using it in the *substitution* string. Instead, you are using `REQUEST_URI` which contains the full root-relative URL-path.

You are also matching `sv` in the URL-path, but redirecting to `se` in the TLD. The following should resolve the issue (with minimal changes):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/se(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.se%1 [L,R=301]
```

Where `%1` is a backreference to the captured subpattern in the preceding *condition* (the `/post` part).

However, You don't need the second (or even the first) condition(s), as it can be all done in the `RewriteRule` directive. There wouldn't seem to be a need to check the requested hostname, since if the language subdirectory is in the URL-path then it would seem you should redirect anyway to remove it.

For example, the following should be sufficient to redirect a single language code:

```
# Language "se"
RewriteRule ^se(?:/(.*))?$ https://www.example.se/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The non-capturing group that contains the slash delimiter ensures that we always have a trailing slash on the target URL (after the hostname). The first rule above requires the user-agent to "correct" the redirect response when the slash after the hostname is omitted (which it does).

For multiple languages you can modify the same rule with regex *alternation*. For example:

```
# All supported languages
RewriteRule ^(se|uk|us|au|id)(?:/(.*))?$ https://www.example.$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This assumes all language codes map to a TLD using the same code. If not then you can implement a "mapping" (lang code -> TLD) in the rule itself or use a `RewriteMap` if you have access to the server config. This could also provide a "default" TLD.

You *could* be more generic and allow any two-character language code in the regex. eg. `^([a-z]{2})(?:/(.*))?$`. And simply pass this through to the TLD. However, a request for an unknown language (eg. `/xx/post`) - which might have resulted from an error on your site - will now result in either a malformed redirect (since the domain won't resolve) or worse, a redirect to a competitor lying in wait. And this might go undetected unless you run an analysis of your redirects. So, being more restrictive with the regex/rule may be advisable.